# How to convert an HTML/javascript SVG animated soundwave to React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to convert some code from a GitHub repo that renders a waveform from a playing audio file, written in HTML and Javascript. My objective is to recreate it in React Native, but it's giving me errors, mainly because I don't seem to translate the animated part. I've stripped the repo code from all that is not necessary to be able to understand it better. But if you want to check the entire repo, you can go here: [Waveform Path](https://github.com/jerosoler/waveform-path)

So here's the short version of the working (Web) code:

## From the Repo

#### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 100 100%22><text y=%22.9em%22 font-size=%2290%22></text></svg>">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="examples">
            <svg class="round" id="example17" height="400px" width="400px">
                <path style=" stroke-width: 2px; fill: none; ">
                    <animate
                    attributeName="d"
                    dur="2.54s"
                    repeatCount="indefinite"
                    values=""
                />
                </path>
            </svg>
        </div>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

#### main.js

```js
import { getAudioData, polarPath } from "./waveform-path.js";

async function AudioPath(file) {
    const audioData = await getAudioData(file);
    // POLAR

    const example17 = polarPath(audioData,{ 
        samples: 100, type: 'steps',
        left: 200, top: 200, distance: 100, length: 100,
        animation: true
     });
    document.querySelector("#example17 path animate").setAttribute('values', example17);
}
AudioPath("hello_world.ogg");

function alerterror() {
    alert("error");
}
```

#### waveform-path.js

```js
export const getAudioData = (url) => {
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    const audioContext = new AudioContext();
    return fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
    .then(arrayBuffer => audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer))
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
};

export const polarPath = (audioBuffer, options) => {
    const { 
        channel = 0,
        samples = audioBuffer.length,
        distance = 50,
        length = 100,
        top = 0,
        left = 0,
        type = 'steps',
        startdeg = 0,
        enddeg = 360,
        invertdeg = false,
        invertpath = false,
        paths = [{d:'Q', sdeg: 0, sr:0, deg: 50, r: 100, edeg:100, er:0}],
        animation = false,
        animationframes = 10,
        normalize = true,
        } = options;
    
    const framesData = getFramesData(audioBuffer, channel, animation, animationframes);
    const filteredData = getFilterData(framesData, samples);
    const normalizeData = (normalize ? getNormalizeData(filteredData) : filteredData);

    let path = ``;
    const fixenddeg = (enddeg < startdeg ? enddeg+360 : enddeg);
    const deg = (!invertdeg ? (fixenddeg-startdeg) / samples : (startdeg-fixenddeg) / samples );
    const fixOrientation = (!invertdeg ? 90+startdeg : 90+startdeg+180 );
    const invert = (!invertpath ? 1 : -1);
    const pathslength = paths.length;
    const fixpathslength =  (type == 'mirror' ? pathslength*2 : pathslength);
    const pi180 = Math.PI / 180;

    const normalizeDataLength = normalizeData.length;

    for(let f = 0; f < normalizeDataLength; f++) {
        if(f>0) {
            const pathlength = path.length;
            const lastvalue = path.charAt(pathlength - 1);
            if(lastvalue == ";" || pathlength === 0) {
                path+=' M 0 0 ;';
            } else {
                path += ';';
            }
        }       

        let last_pos_x = -9999;
        let last_pos_y = -9999;
        
        for (let i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
            const positive =  (type != 'bars' ? (i % 2 ? 1: -1) : 1);
            let mirror = 1;
            for(let j = 0; j < fixpathslength; j++) {
                let k = j;
                if(j >= pathslength) {
                    k = j - pathslength;
                    mirror = -1;   
                }
                paths[k].minshow = paths[k].minshow ?? 0;
                paths[k].maxshow = paths[k].maxshow ?? 1;
                paths[k].normalize = paths[k].normalize ?? false;
                const normalizeDataValue = (paths[k].normalize ? 1 : normalizeData[f][i]);
                if(paths[k].minshow <= normalizeData[f][i] && paths[k].maxshow >= normalizeData[f][i]) {
                    const angleStart =  ((deg*(i+paths[k].sdeg/100)) - fixOrientation) * pi180;
                    const angle =  ((deg*(i+paths[k].deg/100)) - fixOrientation) * pi180;
                    const angleEnd =  ((deg*(i+paths[k].edeg/100)) - fixOrientation) * pi180;

                    const pos_x = left + ((length*(paths[k].sr/100)*normalizeDataValue)* positive*mirror*invert + distance) * Math.cos(angleStart);
                    const pos_y = top + ((length*(paths[k].sr/100)*normalizeDataValue)* positive*mirror*invert + distance) * Math.sin(angleStart);
                    
                    const center_pos_x = left + ((length*(paths[k].r/100)*normalizeDataValue)* positive*mirror*invert + distance) * Math.cos(angle);
                    const center_pos_y = top + ((length*(paths[k].r/100)*normalizeDataValue)* positive*mirror*invert + distance) * Math.sin(angle);

                    const end_pos_x = left + ((length*(paths[k].er/100)*normalizeDataValue)* positive*mirror*invert + distance) * Math.cos(angleEnd);
                    const end_pos_y = top + ((length*(paths[k].er/100)*normalizeDataValue)* positive*mirror*invert + distance) * Math.sin(angleEnd);

                    if(pos_x !== last_pos_x || pos_y !== last_pos_y) {   
                        path += `M ${pos_x} ${pos_y} `;
                    }

                    path += `Q ${center_pos_x} ${center_pos_y} ${end_pos_x} ${end_pos_y} `; 
                    
                    last_pos_x = end_pos_x;
                    last_pos_y = end_pos_y;                             
                }
            }       
        }
    }
    return path;
}

const getFramesData = (audioBuffer, channel, animation, animationframes) => {
    const rawData = audioBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
    
    const framesData = [];
    if(animation) {
        const frames = audioBuffer.sampleRate / animationframes;
        for (let index = 0; index < rawData.length; index += frames) {
            const partraw = rawData.slice(index, index+frames);
            framesData.push(partraw);
        }
    } else {
        framesData.push(rawData);
    }

    return framesData;
}

const getFilterData = (framesData, samples) => {
    const filteredData = [];
    const framesDataLength = framesData.length;
    for(let f = 0; f < framesDataLength; f++) {
        const blockSize = Math.floor(framesData[f].length / samples); // the number of samples in each subdivision
        const filteredDataBlock = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
            let blockStart = blockSize * i; // the location of the first sample in the block
            let sum = 0;
            for (let j = 0; j < blockSize; j++) {
                sum = sum + Math.abs(framesData[f][blockStart + j]); // find the sum of all the samples in the block
            }
            filteredDataBlock.push(sum / blockSize); // divide the sum by the block size to get the average
        }
        filteredData.push(filteredDataBlock);
    }
    return filteredData;   
}

const getNormalizeData = (filteredData) => {
    const multipliers = [];
    const filteredDataLength = filteredData.length
    for(let i = 0; i < filteredDataLength; i++) {
        const multiplier = Math.max(...filteredData[i]);
        multipliers.push(multiplier);
    }
    const maxMultiplier = Math.pow(Math.max(...multipliers), -1);

    const normalizeData = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < filteredDataLength; i++) {
        const normalizeDataBlock = filteredData[i].map(n => n * maxMultiplier);
        normalizeData.push(normalizeDataBlock);
    }
    return normalizeData;
}
```

## From my code

Here's my code for my React native app. 'main.js' is included in App.js, and 'waveform-path.js' is the same:

#### App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Animated } from 'react-native';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
import { getAudioData, polarPath } from "./waveform-path.js";
import { Svg, Path } from 'react-native-svg';

const App = () => {
  const [audioSvg, setAudioSvg] = useState();
  const audioSound = require('./assets/hello_world.ogg');

  // Play a sound //
  const playSound = async () => {
    try {
      const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();
      await soundObject.loadAsync(audioSound);
      await soundObject.playAsync();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error playing sound:', error);
    }
    AudioPath(audioSound);
  };

  // Create Soundwave //
  const AudioPath = async(file) => {
      try {
        const audioData = await getAudioData(file);
        const pathLogo = polarPath(audioData,{
          samples: 100,
          type: 'steps',
          left: 200,
          top: 200,
          distance: 100,
          length: 100,
          animation: true
        });
        setAudioSvg({ d: pathLogo });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error retrieving audio data:', error);
      }
  };

  // Render UI //
  return (
    <View style={styles.main}>
      <View style={styles.topView}>
        <Svg width="100%" height="100%">
          <Path fill="white" stroke="black" {...audioSvg} />
        </Svg>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.bottomView}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={playSound}>
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Play</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  main: {
    flex: 1, 
    padding: 18, 
    paddingTop: 32
  },
    topView: {
      flex: 2, 
      width: '100%'
    },
      waveform: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        overflow: 'hidden',
      },
        waveformPoint: {
          width: 2,
          backgroundColor: 'blue', // Adjust the color as per your preference
        },
    bottomView: {
      flex: 1, 
      justifyContent: 'center', 
      alignItems: 'center' 
    },
      buttonContainer: {
        justifyContent: 'center', 
        alignItems: 'center', 
        width: 150, 
        height: 50, 
        backgroundColor: 'orange', 
        borderRadius: 14
      },
        buttonText: {
          fontSize: 18, 
          fontWeight: 600, 
          color: 'white'
        }

})
export default App;
```

My issue is changing the 'document.querySelector' line in 'main.js'. It results in this error in the console:

> react-dom.development.js:798 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected path command, "…99999999997 100 ;M 200 100 Q 203…".

Why is this happening since the web version seems to work fine?

Comment: Why don't you use `useRef( )` hook?

Comment: If you are accessing content outside the component in react using `querySelector( )` then you may run into issues as the other component may not have been rendered yet. That is why we have `useRef( )` in react.

Comment: Also try putting your app in a [codesand box](https://codesandbox.io)

Comment: waveform-path.js relies on the window.AudioContext and I’m not sure if react native naturally polyfills for this

Comment: I did a quick search for AudioContext on the react native GitHub page and found nothing. I did read an old stackoverflow answer that stated that there are some window polyfills provided out of the box, so it could be that AudioContext is one of those things that isn’t provided